# iOS App Extension Exception Handling

Tags: ios, exception, ios8-share-extension

When an `NSException` is raised in an app extension (e.g. share extension), it seems that this just hangs up the host app (e.g. Safari).

Neither do Exception handlers work, like so:

```
static ShareViewController * shareVC;

// ...

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    shareVC = self;

    NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&exceptionHandler);

    // ...
}

void exceptionHandler(NSException *exception) {
    NSArray *stack = [exception callStackReturnAddresses];
    if (stack.count > 0) {
        [GoogleAnalyticsInterfaceManager trackException:@"An exception occurred"];
    }

    [shareVC.extensionContext completeRequestReturningItems:@[] completionHandler:nil];
}
```

Raising an exception just results in this console entry:

**connection from pid 5922: Warning: Exception caught during decoding of received reply to message '_loadItemForPayload:contextIdentifier:completionHandler:', dropping incoming message and calling failure block.**

So the extension somehow catches the exception internally, but still freezes the host app indefinitely (most likely because `completeRequestReturningItems:completionHandler:` is not called on the view controller?).

iOS Bug?

Comment: Hi @manmal, I am getting the sam error when I am trying to upload the image from an api. My target is to upload the image using share extension to the server. What should I be doing to upload the image?